# How to update multiple HTML form fields with a single AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have:

```
<tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <!-- line below generates a select box with id="product" -->
    <td id="product"><?=$this->formSelect($form->get('product'));?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Description" id="Description" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Quantity" id="Quantity" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Price" id="Price" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Question**

When using `onupdate` feature of jQuery, that is tied to event of changing value of "product" select box, how do I update Description, Quantity and Price fields.

What I have now is this:

```
$("#product").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "updatedescription.php",
        data : 'product_id=' + $(this).val(),
        cache : false,
        success : function(html) {
            $("#Description").html(html);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

But it updates Description only.

**PHP Code**

```
function loadDescriptionByProduct()
{
    $product = filter_var($_POST['product_id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $description = $this->repository->getDescriptionByProduct($product);
    echo $description;
}

function getDescriptionByProduct(string $product)
{
    $sql = "SELECT description FROM product where product=?";
    $result = db_param_query($sql, $product);
    $row = db_fetch_array($result);
    $description = $row['description'];
    return $description;
}
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Asking "which is better" questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: changed question to focus on mechanics of AJAX

Comment: You would send data for each item you want to update. For example: `data: this=1&that=2&theother=3` or you can serialize our form data.

Comment: Add your PHP code for AJAX to your question too. You will likely want to echo out a json_encoded array that contains the values for each of your inputs. Then you can update each input individually in your success handler.

Comment: added the PHP code

Comment: check the updated in my answer @Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a single resource like `getProductDetails.php` and get there all the information related to the product you want.

PHP

```
function getProductDetails(string $product)
{
    $sql = "SELECT price, description FROM product where product=?";
    $result = db_param_query($sql, $product);
    $row = db_fetch_array($result);

    $response = array(
        'price' => $row['price'],
        'desc' => $row['description']
    );

    return json_encode($response); //return a json response.
}
```

Javascript

```
$("#product").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "getProductDetails.php",
        data : 'product_id=' + $(this).val(),
        cache : false,
        success : function(response) {
            var parsedResponse = $.parseJSON(response);

            $("#Description").html(parsedResponse.desc);
            // ...
            $("#Price").html(parsedResponse.price);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Also, you can use `Content-Type: application/json` response header and indicate to jQuery that this is JSON by using the `dataType: 'json'` parameter. (and remove `$.parseJSON()`)

Comment: thanks I'm implementing this now will report back on how it worked.  also you have an extra quote near `row['description']` which throws off color highlighting

Comment: sure no problem, try it! (extra quote removed, thanks)

Comment: yep it does work!